# postgresql nested select with map

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE folder (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE folder_path (
  folder_id integer references folder(id),
  path ltree
);

INSERT INTO folder (id,name) VALUES (1,'f1');
INSERT INTO folder (id,name) VALUES (2,'f2');

INSERT INTO folder_path (folder_id, path) VALUES (1,'1');
INSERT INTO folder_path (folder_id, path) VALUES (2,'1.2');
INSERT INTO folder_path (folder_id, path) VALUES (2,'2');
```

And needs to select all folders with their paths, like this:

```
 [
   { id: 1,
     name: 'f1',
     paths: [
              [{id: 1, name: 'f1'}]
            ]
   }
   { id: 2, 
     name: 'f2',
     paths: [
              [{id: 1, name: 'f1'}, {id: 2, name: 'f2'}],
              [{id: 2, name: 'f2'}]
            ]
 ]
```

How can I do this? Thanks.
sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6b974/12

Comment: Unrelated (and probably just because of the demo) but: if you have a sequence for the default value of a column you should not provide explicit values for that column. This way the sequence and the values in the table get out of sync.

Comment: Yes, it's for demo purposes only and unnecessary